# Numerical quadrature for the complex antiderivative

Tags: numerical-methods, complex-integration

My goal is to take a complex-differentiable function $f:\Bbb C\rightarrow\Bbb C$ and a value $z$ and approximate $F(z)$, where $F$ is one of the functions such that $F^\prime(z)=f(z)$ for all $z$. Now, if $f$ was a real function, this would be simple; one could just take $$F(x)=\begin{cases}\int_0^xf(x)\,\text dx,&\text{if $x\geq0$}\\-\int_x^0f(x)\,\text dx,&\text{if $x<0$}\end{cases}$$ and use standard numerical quadrature.

However, this doesn't appear to apply at all on the complex plane. First off, "the signed area under the curve" definition of a definite integral doesn't appear to apply even for a function $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb C$; I'd guess that one should just add the complex numbers, but I cannot find any preexisting methods of numerical quadrature for functions of this type. Secondly, I'm not sure which definite integral I would have to take for a specific value of $z$. I've read something about path integrals and contours, but I do not see how they would apply here. Over all, my question is: **how would I go about approximating values of the complex antiderivative?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume all you know about $f$ is that it is complex-differentiable and you can evaluate it at a point.

Since $f$ is complex-differentiable it can be expressed as a power series
\begin{align*}
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(z_{0})}{n!}(z - z_{0})^{n}
\end{align*}
Integrating term by term we have
\begin{align*}
F(z) = C + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(z_{0})}{(n+1)!}(z - z_{0})^{n+1}
\end{align*}
So all you need is a numerical algorithm to evaluate $f^{(n)}(z_{0})$ for sufficiently many $n$.
Using Cauchy's differentiation formula
\begin{align*}
f^{(n)}(z_{0}) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_{0})^{n+1}} \, \mathrm{d}z = \frac{n!}{r^{n}} \int_{0}^{1} f(z_{0} + re^{2\pi i\theta})e^{-2\pi in\theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta
\end{align*}
where $r$ is sufficiently small to not enclose any poles of $f$.
A necessary condition on $r$ is that
\begin{align*}
\oint f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z = \int_{0}^{1} f(z_{0} + re^{2\pi i\theta}) \, \mathrm{d}\theta = 0
\end{align*}
which follows from the residue theorem. In rare cases there could be pole cancellation, so you might also want to assert that the identity
\begin{align*}
 f(z_{0}) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint \frac{f(z)}{z - z_{0}} \, \mathrm{d}z
\end{align*}
holds. In order for both these tests to pass, not only do the poles have to cancel, they have to solve a linear system, so if you choose an $r$ where both these identities hold you are almost certainly in the clear.

Since the integrands are periodic, simple trapezoidal quadrature converges exponentially and computing $n$ integrands is little more work than computing 1. This is because once we've computed a sample $f_{k} := f(z_{0} + re^{2\pi i\theta_{k}})$, then we just store that value and get the rest of the integrals just by repeated multiplications by $e^{-2\pi i\theta_{k}}$. Expect about 30 calls to $f$ to obtain double precision.

This is riffing off the ideas of [Lyness and Moler](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9082/fb5cc7ed40d88e6c78b10bbd736a1c0c42d5.pdf) who recognized that numerical differentiation by contour integration is numerically stable and fast. They weren't interested in complex antidifferentiation, but nonetheless the idea seems to apply here.

Comment: Luckily, I don't think the users will be trying to trick the system in my use case :P

Comment: @LegionMammal978: What's your application for this?

Comment: Literally a numerical antiderivative function in a system that supports complex numbers (also, what do you mean by the repeated multiplication bit?)

Comment: @LegionMammal978: Is it open source?

Comment: So far, a) it's an early work in progress, b) it's on my local computer, and c) I'm just starting to implement this.

Comment: @LegionMammal978: You might want to check out my adaptive trapezoidal quadrature: https://github.com/boostorg/math/pull/59

Comment: The key idea that most people miss is the L1 norm estimation which measures the condition number of the summation problem. I haven't tried to get it to work with complex numbers though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56745/discussion-between-legionmammal978-and-user14717).